# How to manipulate output from commands with shell scripts

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

Having a `ls -l` command it makes a list on the command prompt and if we want to manipulate it we pipeline it with `awk` command, for instance if we want to  to show specific files.

Is that possible without using the `awk` command but instead using a shell script, if so what would be the column variables how would we manipulate that on fly list do you have also any suggestions on educative links or books.

---

EDIT:for example a `ls -l|awk '{print $1}'` the `$1` is referring to the first column,is there any way to do that with a shell script variable, for instance if we would like to run the `ls -l` command inside a shell script and print the exact filenames of which we are searching for. How to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add an example of what you are describing. I _think_ you are asking how you can manipulate text in columns through a shell script, is that so?

Comment: You should not parse the output of `ls` if you have filenames with spaces and/or newlines there is no way you parse the output.

Answer (score 3):

Your question right now is not so clear, but I'll have a stab at one of the things I think you are referring to.

If you want to write a script or program that can be used in a pipeline, it must read from [standard input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_input) and write to standard output.  For example, a bash script that adds line numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

index=1
while read line; do
    echo $index". "$line
    index=$(($index + 1))
done
```

If this is called `eg.sh` you could use it:

```
ls -1 | ./eg.sh
cat ./eg.sh | ./eg.sh | grep "^5\."
```

The last one should print out just:

```
5. echo $index". "$line
```

The key to getting the input is the `read` built-in [(here's some details)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_08_02).

Comment: I 've done some research and I want to ask,in awk command $1,$2 e.t.c. are referring to the file's or the command's columns, which are the equivalent variables in shell script for example in a loop "read number name" it reads the first variable of each line of a file how we read the others "columns" of that file separetely?is there any any way or awk is mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question, but in the simplest case, where you have space-separated columns of text and no spaces within fields, you could do:

```
echo "col1 col2 col3 col4" | while read one two three four; do echo "$two"; done
```

The `while read [variable names]` shell loop will automatically split its input at whitespace into as many variables as you give.